# How does jquery ui init calendar data?

Tags: javascript, calendar, initialization

This is kind of general wonderment. I am curious about how jquery ui datapicker initializes the calendar view. More exactly is how does it know how many days are there in a specific given month in any future year and which weekday that day is ? Is there some kind of algorithms to predict these data? Currently I am working on an application. We are kind of initializing the calendar data manually. I am wondering if there is a way to populate our calendar table automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I know of to get the day of the week is to use the getDay method of the javascript date object:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
```

n will be a number from 0-6
see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp

To find which years are leap years, refer to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175521/javascript-to-find-leap-year)