# Get next birthday in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection with events in time with the date. Something like this:

```
{
    "year"  : 1985,
    "month" : 4,
    "day"   : 16,
    "name"  : "J"
},
{
    "year"  : 1985,
    "month" : 9,
    "day"   : 16,
    "name"  : "E"
},
{
    "year"  : 1950,
    "month" : 11,
    "day"   : 11,
    "name"  : "M"
},
{
    "year"  : 1947,
    "month" : 5,
    "day"   : 6,
    "name"  : "D"
}
```

**I want a MongoDB query that returns next birthday starting today**. For instance, if today was September 25th, next birthday in my collection would be November 11th, corresponding to the entry with `name` equal to `"M"`.

I would accept adding fields of type `Date`, removing my current `year`, `month` and `day` fields, or whatever in order to have an efficient way to achieve my goal.

I'm using MongoDB v3.4.

Comment: I assume you want to wrap right?  So in your case if today was December 12, you'd want to return the entry by the name "J" because it's the next month?

Comment: @MichaelPlatt yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got an answer following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041785/find-whether-someone-got-a-birthday-in-the-next-30-days-with-mongo). It uses [the Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions).

First of all, I decided to use `Date`/`ISODate` type to store birthdays, instead of individual year/month/day fields. So my `test` collection would  have these entries:

```
{
    "birthday" : ISODate("1985-04-16T10:00:00.000Z"),
    "name" : "J"
}

{
    "birthday" : ISODate("1985-09-16T11:00:00.000Z"),
    "name" : "E"
}

{
    "birthday" : ISODate("1950-11-11T11:00:00.000Z"),
    "name" : "M"
}

{
    "birthday" : ISODate("1947-05-06T10:00:00.000Z"),
    "name" : "D"
}
```

Then, I constructed a few structures to use in aggregation pipeline:

1. In `pDayOfYear` get sequential year of the year of the birthday and today, using [$dayOfYear operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfYear/).
2. In `pLeapYear` subtract 1 to `dayofYear` field if `birthday` was in a leap year and calculate the difference between each birthday and today.
3. In `pPast` add 365 to past birthdays to have `positiveDiff` field.
4. In `pSort` sort results by `positiveDiff` field in descending order, so we can can have a list of next birthdays
5. In `pFirst` get only the first result.

Query would look like:

```
pDayOfYear = {
    "$project": {
        "birthday": 1,
        "todayDayOfYear": {"$dayOfYear": new ISODate()},
        "leap": {"$or": [
            {"$eq": [0, {"$mod": [{"$year": "$birthday"}, 400]}]},
            {"$and": [
                {"$eq": [0, {"$mod": [{"$year": "$birthday"}, 4]}]},
                {"$ne": [0, {"$mod": [{"$year": "$birthday"}, 100]}]}
            ]}
        ]},
        "dayOfYear": {"$dayOfYear": "$birthday"}
    }
}

pLeapYear = {
    "$project": {
        "birthday": 1,
        "todayDayOfYear": 1,
        "dayOfYear": {
            "$subtract": [
                "$dayOfYear",
                {
                    "$cond": [
                        {"$and":
                             ["$leap",
                              {"$gt": ["$dayOfYear", 59]}
                              ]},
                        1,
                        0]
                }
            ]},
         "diff": { "$subtract": [ "$dayOfYear", "$todayDayOfYear"] }
    }
}


pPast = {
    "$project": {
        "diff": 1,
        "birthday": 1,
        "positiveDiff": {
            "$cond": { 
                "if": { "$lt": ["$diff", 0 ]},
                    "then": { "$add": ["$diff", 365] },
                "else":  "$diff"
                },
            }
    }
}

pSort = {
        "$sort": {
            "positiveDiff": 1
        }
}


pFirst = {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "first_birthday",
        "first": {
            "$first": "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}

db.getCollection('tests').aggregate(pDayOfYear, pLeapYear, pPast, pSort, pFirst);
```

So I would get next birthday ID and I could query the field by ID. One can get next birthday of an specific date changing `todayDayOfYear`field by any date.

I'm open to any change, specially readability and efficiency improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so best I can tell you essentially need two queries to make this work.  I'm not a Mongo expert but this will get you what you need for now/put you in the right direction for research.  The two queries are as follows:

```
db.YOUR_COLLECTION.find({ $where: "this.year = input_year & this.month > input_month & this.day > input_day" }).sort({ month: 1, day: 1 }) 
// Gets you back all the entries that have a month greater than the input month.

db.YOUR_COLLECTION.find({ $where: "this.year > input_year }).sort({ year: 1, month: 1, day: 1 }) 
// Gets you back all the entries that start at next year and go forward.  This could probably be optimized a bit at some point.
```

Note that in the first case I'm ordering them on month first, then day in ascending order and the second orders by year as an extra parameter.  I'm also returning all the rows.  In practice, you may want to do something like a limit to one result.  Either way, you'll need to run the first query to handle a case where the next date isn't wrapped into the next year.  If that returns no results, then you'll want the second query that will start in the following year and search forward.  If this doesn't fully answer your question let me know.