# JQuery - Calculate date and month 5 years from today

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok!! I am trying to get date and month exactly 5 years ago from today's date in JQuery.

The main thing i am missing that i have to take care of leap years also and that i am struggling with.

I have tried below function

```
function printFiveYears()
{   
    var fiveYears = new Date();
    fiveYears.setTime(fiveYears.valueOf() - 5 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    window.alert("5 years ago, the time and date were: " + fiveYears.toString());
}
```

But here, i am directly subtracting 365 days which is not right. Let me know corrections please.

Ps: No external plugins please.

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: @JamesDonnelly ... not with external plugins please

Comment: would you be willing to do an ajax call with a php script....

Comment: nops.. only Jquery solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353211/check-if-year-is-leap-year-in-javascript

Comment: @apaul34208 ... how can i include this into my function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

```
var now = new Date();
var five_years_ago = new Date(now.getFullYear()-5,now.getMonth(),now.getDay());
```

And if you want, add to hours, minutes and seconds.

I hope it helps.

Comment: does it take care of leap year? and i want only month date ad year.. not full timstamp

Comment: I see 2 issues with this answer. First, it does not take care of leap year. Second, `getDay()` method only returns the week day. So for today, 5/13/2015, get day will return you 3. You should use `.getDate()` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(function() {
            $('[type="date"]').prop('min', function() {
                return new Date().toJSON().split('T')[0];
            });

            $('[type="date"]').prop('max', function() {
                var myDate = new Date((new Date()).getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                var newDate = (myDate.toJSON().split('T')[0]);
                return newDate;
            });
        });
```