# Set value of input type date bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 fields input and output dates. On certain conditions I set the endDate to be 1 year ahead of start date.

```
<input type='date' id='endDate'>
```

```js
$("#startDate").change(function(){
    var endDate = new Date($("#startDate").val());
    endDate.setMonth(endDate.getMonth() + 1);
    endDate.setFullYear(endDate.getFullYear() + 1);
    var myDay = ("0" + endDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var myMonth = ("0" + endDate.getMonth()).slice(-2);
    $("#endDate").val(endDate.getFullYear() + '-' + myMonth + '-' + myDay);
}
```

The issue when I set the start date to 2-29-2016
I got the following error:

> The specified value "2017-02-29" does not conform to the required
>   format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

I expected the Date() function to take care of it. Apparently, they don't. Is this a bug?

Is their anyway faster than adding a bunch of **if** statements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The real problem here is that you've used the value of `getMonth` without adding 1 to it. The value from `getMonth` starts at 0 (January), but month values in your `yyyy-MM-dd` format start with 1.

So:

```
var myMonth = ("0" + (endDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
// Note -------------^------------------^^^^^
```

That's how you ended up with an invalid string, `2017-02-29`, despite having used the `Date` object, which will indeed ensure it only gives you valid dates. The `Date` object contained the date **March** 29th, not February 29th.

However:

> On certain conditions I set the endDate to be 1 year ahead of start date.

Your code doesn't do that. It adds a year **and a month**, not just a year:

```
endDate.setMonth(endDate.getMonth() + 1);       // <== Changing month
endDate.setFullYear(endDate.getFullYear() + 1);
```

If you only want to add a year, remove the first of those two lines. That, combined, with the correction to how you're using `getMonth` when forming the string, will reliably add a year to the date (with possible month rollover).

So:

```
$("#startDate").change(function(){
    var endDate = new Date($("#startDate").val());
    endDate.setFullYear(endDate.getFullYear() + 1);
    var myDay = ("0" + endDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var myMonth = ("0" + (endDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    $("#endDate").val(endDate.getFullYear() + '-' + myMonth + '-' + myDay);
});
```

Answer (score 10):

> The specified value "2017-02-29" does not conform to the required
>   format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

`2017-02-29` is not a valid date. `29th feb` of next year (2017) is not possible.

**Only leap years have february Month of 29.**

Try `2016-02-29` instead.

> Is their anyway faster than adding a bunch of if statements?

No need to add bunch of if statements, you can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16353241/1984039)

```
function leapYear(year)
{
  return ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
}
```

For answering your question, if you set the date explicitly like "2017-02-29" then it will throw an error.

Just make changes in the date object itself and apply that date object to the input by

```
  $("#endDate").val( endDate.toJSON().slice(0,10) );
```

Now it should take care of rolling over to next month.

**Edit (based on TJ's comment)**

Leap years occur every year that is evenly divisible by 4 except ones evenly divisible by 100 (which are not leap years), except ones evenly divisible by 400 (which are leap years).

Comment: Leap years occur every year that is evenly divisible by 4 *except* ones evenly divisible by 100 (which are not leap years), *except* ones evenly divisible by 400 (which *are* leap years).

Comment: Yes I know that this is an issue of leap years. But my question is, shouldn't the Date() function take care of it? Or should I do it manually?

Comment: @Syntax_Error check the my updated post about how to set updated date to the input date. Let me know if this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I overcame this bug by adding

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
```