# Javascript homework assistance

Tags: javascript

I'm in the most javascript class and I really don't understand it and I'm stumped on this question. I have trying many different ways for quite a while now, but just can't seem to figure it out. 
Problem:
Here are the rules to determine if a particular year is or is not a leap year:
Any year that is divisible by 400 is a leap year.
Of the remaining years, any year that is divisible by 100 is not a leap year.
Of the remaining years, any year that is divisible by 4 is a leap year.
All other years are not leap years.
Write JavaScript code that reads a year from the user and displays either Leap year or Not a leap year, whichever is correct.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does "the most javascript class" mean? The most *what*?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
function leapYear(year)
{
  return ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
}
```

I got the above from the weblink below. Please make sure you check to see if your question has been previously asked and answered. If a similar question has been asked, it is good to explain why the answer does not work for you. Hope this helps.

[Check if year is leap year in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353211/check-if-year-is-leap-year-in-javascript)

P.S. Welcome to SO.

Comment: If the question is answered completely in another question, don't post an answer, just flag it as a duplicate.