# How to check using AngularJS if date existed before like February 29 2014?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

How to check using AngularJS if date existed before like February 29 2014?

Because separately February 29 is valid date, but February 29 2014 did not exist.

For example I am trying to use angular.isDate():

```
var date = new Date(2014, 02, 29);
var isValidDate = angular.isDate(date);
```

JavaScript still creates Date Object: March 01 2014, because February 29 2014 did not exist and that is and angular.isDate() returns **true**

Comment: new Date(2014, 02, 29) is actually March 29, since the month begins with 0 for January

Answer (score 0):

[angular.isDate()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/4daafd3dbe6a80d578f5a31df1bb99c77559543e/src/Angular.js#L581) just does a simple check of the type of the object you pass to it.

You have to check if it is a valid date before calling Date: [See here how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433119/1494616)